# Open inline link in modal/colorbox

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have the colorbox module installed so I assume there's a way to do this with it, but I've had no success. Pretty much what I'd like to do within the WYSIWYG editor is have a link to an external website open up in a colorbox modal. I have forms hosted on a third party website, so instead of having users leave my site, I'd like the ability to have them just see that external form in the colorbox.

How do I achieve such a thing? I've tried adding the `colorbox-node` class to no success and also tried creating my own class and then in a custom js file have the following code:

```
 (function($){
    $(".custom-class").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
 }(jQuery));
```

The above code fails when I inspect it with the following error:
`TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function`.

I'm also using a bootstrap sub-theme but I don't think the modal component would be of any use, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure the library is added to the request.

For example, to include the library on every page:

```
function THEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'colorbox/colorbox';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This allows me to add the colorbox library to load on every page but it seems to load the library after my active.js file so it doesn't recognize my `.colorbox` function. Is there a way of sorting the order of how the js files are loaded?

Comment: Let define add colorbox library in  **dependencies** of your library. So colorbox library will loaded before your library load.

Comment: @MrD can you elaborate on what you mean/how to do this?

Comment: Nevermind, I get what you mean. Adding it as a dependency to the libraries.yml file adds it before my custom js. Thank you.